# Enzyme simulate an onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I'm testing a react component with Mocha and Enzyme. Here is the component (shortened for simplicity of course):

```
class New extends React.Component {

  // shortened for simplicity

  handleChange(event) {
    // handle changing state of input

    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name
    this.setState({[name]: value})

  }


  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group row">
            <label className="col-2 col-form-label form-text">Poll Name</label>
            <div className="col-10">
              <input
                className="form-control"
                ref="pollName"
                name="pollName"
                type="text"
                value={this.state.pollName}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <input className="btn btn-info"  type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And here is the test:

```
it("responds to name change", done => {
  const handleChangeSpy = sinon.spy();
  const event = {target: {name: "pollName", value: "spam"}};
  const wrap = mount(
    <New handleChange={handleChangeSpy} />
  );

  wrap.ref('pollName').simulate('change', event);
  expect(handleChangeSpy.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
})
```

I am expecting that when the user types text into the `<input>` box the `handleChange` method will be called. The test above fails with:

```
AssertionError: expected false to equal true
+ expected - actual

-false
+true

at Context.<anonymous> (test/components/new_component_test.js:71:45)
```

My objective is to test that the method `handleChange` is called. How can I do that?

Comment: You can spy an object's method directly using `sinon.spy(object, "method")`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can simply spy to the method directly via the prototype.

```
it("responds to name change", done => {
  const handleChangeSpy = sinon.spy(New.prototype, "handleChange");
  const event = {target: {name: "pollName", value: "spam"}};
  const wrap = mount(
    <New />
  );
  wrap.ref('pollName').simulate('change', event);
  expect(handleChangeSpy.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
})
```

Alternatively, you can use spy on the instance's method, but you have to make a forced update because the component is already rendered after mount is called, which means the onChange is already bound to its original.

```
it("responds to name change", done => {
  const event = {target: {name: "pollName", value: "spam"}};
  const wrap = mount(
    <New />
  );
  const handleChangeSpy = sinon.spy(wrap.instance(), "handleChange");
  wrap.update(); // Force re-render
  wrap.ref('pollName').simulate('change', event);
  expect(handleChangeSpy.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
})
```

Comment: Hmm strange. I get the following error when trying the second approach.      

TypeError: wrap.ref(...).simulate is not a function

Comment: Hi, I am new to Enzyme and testing on ReactJS, what is the purpose of "done" in this line:  `done => {...}`? Thanks

Comment: @AKJ `done` is part of the mocha framework. To run tests asynchronously, you call `done()` when the test is done.