# Enzyme simulate.('change', event) not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I am trying to perform unit test for my react app using karma/jasmine. The test is to check whether the state has changed or not. I have gone through several references but can't seem to work out the problem. Besides, spyOn() and sinon.spy() are giving erroneous output.

```
expect(received).toBe(expected)

Expected value to be (using ===):
  true
Received:
  false
```

> test-snippet

```
        it('should call handleUserIdChange', () => {
            const value = '00000000';
            const mountedComponentHandle = mount(<LoginForm />);
            const onChangeUserID = sinon.spy(mountedComponentHandle.instance(), 'handleUserIdChange');
            mountedComponentHandle.update();
            (mountedComponentHandle.find('ValidatedInput').at(0)).simulate('change', value);
            expect(
                onChangeUserID.calledOnce
            ).toBe(true);
        });
```

> Login.js for which tests are written

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userId : '',
            password : '',
            loginType : ['Customer', 'Payer', 'Super-User'],
            userType : 'Customer',
            isLoggedIn : false,
            loginResponse : '',
            FieldsRegister : [],
        }
        this.handleClearForm = this.handleClearForm.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmitForm = this.handleSubmitForm.bind(this);
        this.handleUserIdChange = this.handleUserIdChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
        this.handleUserTypeChangeSelect = this.handleUserTypeChangeSelect.bind(this);
        this.handleRegisterFormFields = this.handleRegisterFormFields.bind(this);
    }

    handleUserIdChange(value) {
        this.setState({ userId : value });
    }

    handlePasswordChange(value) {
        this.setState({ password : value });
    }
    ....
    render() {
        return (
            <form className="container form-horizontal"  onSubmit={this.handleSubmitForm}>
              <div className=" pb-10">
                <h2 className="text-center">Login</h2>
              </div>
              <div className='column text-center'>
                <span>{this.state.loginResponse}</span>
              </div>
                <ValidatedInput
                    name={'userId'}
                    type={'text'}
                    title={'User ID'}
                    value={this.state.userId}
                    placeholder={'Enter User ID'}
                    onChange={this.handleUserIdChange}
                    onComponentMounted={this.handleRegisterFormFields}
                    validations={/^[0-9]{4,10}$/}
                    validationError={'This is not valid user Id'}
                    isRequired={true}
                />
....
```

> ValidateInput.js

```
class ValidatedInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            validations: this.props.validations,
            validationError: this.props.validationError
        };

        this.handleChangeValue = this.handleChangeValue.bind(this);
        this.isValid = this.isValid.bind(this);
        this.validateInput = this.validateInput.bind(this);
    }

    handleChangeValue(e) {
        this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
        var isValidField = this.isValid(e.target);
    }
....
render () {
        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-5 text-center">
                    <label htmlFor={this.props.name}>{this.props.title}</label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-5 text-center">
                    <input
                        className="form-input text-center"
                        type={this.props.type}
                        ref={this.props.name}
                        name={this.props.name}
                        value={this.props.value}
                        required={this.props.isRequired}
                        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                        onChange={this.handleChangeValue}
                    />
                    <span className='Error'></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Any help regarding how to check whether `state.userId` has changed or not and suggestions on how to get the test to pass?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found the error and the cause of it. [Refer this for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426885/enzyme-simulate-an-onchange-event).

Updated test-snippet:

```
it('should call handleUserIdChange', () => {
    const value = '00000000';
    const mountedComponentHandle = mount(<LoginForm />);
    const onChangeUserId = sinon.spy(mountedComponentHandle.instance(), 'handleUserIdChange');
    mountedComponentHandle.update();
    mountedComponentHandle.find('input').at(0).simulate('change', value);
    expect(
        onChangeUserId.called
    ).toBe(true);
});
```

We need to get native element `input` for simulating change in input field.

Answer (score 1):

If worth for someone, I had this issue and I solve it by using **"mount" instead "shallow"** from enzyme. Once you change it, the simulate "change" will **work properly**.

Comment: It happened the other way around to me... Would be nice to understand why...

Answer (score 0):

So for your tests, it looks like you're trying to see whether or not `handleUserIdChange` has been called or not. In which case you need to define `handleUserIdChange` as the `sinonSpy()` and pass it into the `LoginForm` component's props.

```
it('should call handleUserIdChange', () => {
  const value = '001251623';
  const handleUserIdChangeSpy = sinon.spy();
  const mountedComponentHandle = mount(<LoginForm handleUserIdChange={handleUserIdChangeSpy} />);

  mountedComponentHandle.find('ValidatedInput').at(0).simulate('change', value)

  expect(handleUserIdChangeSpy.calledOnce).toBe(true);
});
```

As for your question at the bottom, if you want to check and see if the state has updated once called, you can simply mock the input and check the state using `.state()` after you call a function or interact with your component in a way that should/should not effect the state.

```
it('should update userId', () => {
   const mountedComponentHandle = mount(<LoginForm />);
   const value = '001251623';

   mountedComponentHandle.find('ValidatedInput').at(0).simulate('change', value)
   expect(mountedComponentHandle.state().userId).to.equal(value);
});
```

Comment: The first test still fails with the same error. Moreover, the second test fails too.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then looking for the component display name `.find('ValidatedInput')` pass in the component (constructor) itself `.find(ValidatedInput)`